# SPARQL Query for OWL File (Semantic web)

Tags: sparql, protege

at the moment I am writing my master thesis and got an "OWL" file from my professor but I am not able to get a single query to work.
I wanted to ask if someone could help me out?
Shouldn't be more than 3 lines of code but I can't get it running.

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards
Jonas

Comment: it is impossible to help you here without showing the ontology and the SPARQL query that didn't work ... please edit your question and add the missing details